# Iterate object in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ngfor

[image]

I have this object, and I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? I think this is easy solveable if you have a *ngIf in *ngIf

Comment: This question is probably not specific to Angular it is just JavaScript. Anyway you might use a pipe to transform your Object into arrays so you can easily use *ngFor

Comment: I've tried to create a custom pipe, but without success.. I'm missing something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate over objects with ngFor.

First transform your object into an array which is "simple" JavaScript. Anyway you could do this within a pipe to safe performance but it is not required. Your output has to be something like this:

```
[{
 letter: 'C',
 cities: [{id: 1, name: 'Cisinau'}, {id: 10, name: 'Cluj Napoca'}]
},
{
 letter: 'I',
 cities: [{id: 3, name: 'Iasi'}]
}]
```

Then you could use ngFor for each letter-group and another ngFor for each city.

To transform your object into such an array try this pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'objectToArray'})
export class ObjectToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): {letter: string, cities: any[]}[] {
    let result = [];

    Object.keys(value).map((key)=> {
        let group = {letter: key, cities: []});

        Object.keys(value[key]).map((key2)=> {
            group.cities.push(value[key][key2];
        });

        result.push(group);   
    });

    return result;
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of (allDestinations | objectToArray)">
    {{group.letter}}
    <ng-container *ngFor="let city of group.cities">
        {{ city.name }}
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: An how to use this pipe ? My data is coming from the server in destinations.component.ts

Comment: You can use it within your template. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `entries.pipe.ts`

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'entries'}) export default class {
  transform = Object.entries; 
}
```

In `app.module.ts` (or whatnot)

```
import EntriesPipe from 'entries.pipe';

@ngModule({
  declarations: [EntriesPipe],
  exports: [EntriesPipe]
})
```

in your view

```
<ul *ngFor="let entry of myObject | entries">
  <li>key: {{entry[0]}}</li>
  <li>value: {{entry[1]}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: He would still have a second object within the array that he cant iterate over

Comment: He did not specify nested flattening but that can be achieved well as you have written above. It just seems like a surprising default behavior. A very useful behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use Object methods

```
Object.keys(object).map((key)=> {
    console.log(key); // key
    console.log(object[key]); // value
});
```